# IMPORT XML does not import data from Steam

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I use the same script in Google Sheets for 2 game pages of Steam:

1. IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/41014";"//*[@id='appHubAppName']")
2. IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1069690";"//*[@id='appHubAppName']")

1 - works, 2 - not. What's wrong?

Comment: What does "2 - not" mean? Maybe this answer is helpfull: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114124

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed this means that 1st line of code works while the 2nd line, which is absolutely similar, but with a different link, - does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<div id="appHubAppName"` in the source of the second URL. In fact, you must first give your age before. Since google collects data from the web, google can't tell the site how old it is!

Comment: There is such an ID. Here is the link with a screen. https://gyazo.com/1ec80f6c47b82ce7e3291bd235fd2046

Comment: How can I give my age before? Being logged in on Google and Steam does not improve the situation. Import from the 2nd URL is still not possible :(

Comment: ok, you can get the source of the code after you were logged in the site and after you gave you age (memorized as a cookie i presume) ... google can't do that! no way with google app script ... may be with Selenium but I don't know how to do that